What error/http status code is returned when calling Twilio's ValidationRequestResource.CreateAsync and the requets quota has been reached?
I am currently working implementing outgoing caller id's for voice communication through Twilio by calling this code:
var validationRequest = await ValidationRequestResource.CreateAsync(...)
This article (https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/rate-limits-and-timeouts) says there is a request quota per minute/hour/day.
Does anyone know what error/http status code is returned when the request quota has been reached? 429? Something else?
Thanks!

It is very likely that you will receive the error with http status code 429 (Too Many Requests). Furthermore, a payload is also sent with some information about the error.
Something similar to this will arrive:


{
    "code": XXXXX,
    "message": "Rate limit exceeded",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/XXXXX",
    "status": 429
}



